# Writing correct views to display restaurant food menus

Tags: django, django-views

I am creating a webapp for a new restaurant and want to display the different food menus for people to view and owner to be able to update and delete items from the menu when appropriate. I have a model for the menus and the items on the menu

```
"""
A Menu represents a collection of categories of food items. For example,
a restaurant may have a Lunch menu, and a Dinner menu.
"""


class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=246, unique=True,)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=24, unique=True, help_text='The slug is the URL friendly version of the menu name, so that this can be accessed at a URL like mysite.com/menus/dinner/.')
    additional_text = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Any additional text that the menu might need, i.e. Served between 11:00am and 4:00pm.')
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, help_text='The order of the menu determines where this menu appears alongside other menus.')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'menu name'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


"""
A Menu Category represents a grouping of items within a specific Menu.
An example of a Menu Category would be Appetizers, or Pasta.
"""


class MenuCategory(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, null=True, help_text='The menus that this category belongs to, i.e. \'Lunch\'.', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name='menu category name')
    additional_text = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, help_text='The additional text is any bit of related information to go along with a menu category, i.e. the \'Pasta\' category might have details that say \'All entrees come with salad and bread\'.')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='The order is the order that this category should appear in when rendered on the templates.')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'menu category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'menu categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


"""
A Menu Item is an item of food that the restaurant makes. A Menu Item can
belong to multiple Menu Categories to facilitate menus that have the same item
across multiple menus.
"""


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    CLASSIFICATION_CHOICES = (
        ('neither', 'Neither'),
        ('vegan', 'Vegan'),
        ('vegetarian', 'Vegetarian'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=48, help_text='Name of the item on the menu.')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True, help_text='The description is a simple text description of the menu item.')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(MenuCategory, blank=True, verbose_name='menu category', help_text='Category is the menu category that this menu item belongs to, i.e. \'Appetizers\'.')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='order', help_text='The order is to specify the order in which items show up on the menu.')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, help_text='The price is the cost of the item.')

    classification = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CLASSIFICATION_CHOICES, default=0, verbose_name='classification', help_text='Select if this item classifies as Vegetarian, Vegan, or Neither.')
    spicy = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='spicy?', help_text='Is this item spicy?')
    contains_peanuts = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='contain peanuts?', help_text='Does this item contain peanuts?')
    gluten_free = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='gluten free?', help_text='Is this item Gluten Free?')

    def menu_name(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.category.all()])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'menu item'
        verbose_name_plural = 'menu items'
        verbose_name = 'menu name'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

when someone goes to the menu page I want them to see a list of menus available to click and view i.e
**Breakfast**,
**Lunch**,
**Al La Carte**,
**Dessert**,
**Childrens**.

I am currently struggling trying create the views to list the available menus

```
def listMenus(request):
    menu = Menu.objects.get()

    context = {
        'name': name
    }

    return render('menu/menu.html', context)
```

I get an error get() returned more than one Menu -- it returned 5!

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I am inexperienced and still learning.

Comment: use `Menu.objects.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menu = Menu.objects.get()` this line is wrong.
To get all the menus you should use `Menu.objects.all()`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects).
If you want to get 1 single object, you would want to specify the PK of that object. Such as `Menu.objects.get(pk=1)` will give you the menu with pk 1.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, can you please accept as correct answer? Thanks